# I need to add an \& before the name of the last authors in the bibliography ( if number of authors is $\leq 8$)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bst

I need to add an "ampersand" before the name of the last author in the bibliography ( if number of authors is =< 8)
now it looks like this : [image]

I need it to look like this (notice the ampersand before the last author name) [image]

I am using a mnras.bst file but it is not updated to include this option and I need to edit it. thanking you in advance  for any suggested solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to modify the .bst file to include an ampersand before the name of the last author

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the last comma should also be removed : ", &" doesn't look nice.

Comment: @Julien Puydt thank you for your reply, yes you are right. but how to force the .bst file to produce an ampersand before the last author name?